# How to calculate this integration accurately

Tags: numerical-integration

I need to calculate this integration:

$\int_0^{2 \pi}\int_0^{2 \pi}\int_0^{2 \pi}\ F(x,y,z)  $

which:

$F(x,y,z)=\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
f(x,y,z)^2 & & {0 \leq f(x,y,z)}\\
0        & & {True}
\end{array} \right.$

$f(x,y,z)=\sin (x+y)-\sin (x+z)-\cos (y-z)$

Firstly I tried to  calculate this integration by using `NIntegrate`. it is not work.

```
p = 2*Pi;
f[x_, y_, z_] := Sin[x + y] - Cos[y - z] - Sin[x + z];
P = ImplicitRegion[f[x, y, z] >= 0, {{x, 0, p}, {y, 0, p}, {z, 0, p}}];
NIntegrate[f[x, y, z]^2, Element[{x, y, z} , P]]
(*NIntegrate[f[x,y,z]^2,{x,y,z}\[Element]P]*)
```

Then i can get result after setting the option `Method -> "MonteCarlo"`,but the question is that the result is not stable.
so what can i do to get the accurate result.any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the function is easy to change the region.

```
p = 2*Pi;
f[x_, y_, z_] = Sin[x + y] - Cos[y - z] - Sin[x + z];
NIntegrate[
 f[x, y, z]^2*Boole[f[x, y, z] >= 0], {x, 0, p}, {y, 0, p}, {z, 0, p},
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

> `239.804`